# Mocha unit test: how to forcefully stop execution of test after timeout exceeded

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

I am running unit test using mocha, I want to forcefully timeout, if the function exceeds 30000, so I have set this.timeout(30000);

to verify its working I put infinite loop inside test case, even timeout exceeds test doesn't return back. I want this test to stop executing after timeout.

Here is the test

```
    it('should forcefully timeout',function(done) {
    this.timeout(30000);
     while(1) {
        for(var i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
            if( i % 2 == 0 ) {
                console.log("here");
                for(var i=0; i < 10000; i++) {
                    if( i % 2 == 0 ) {
                        console.log("here1");  
                    }
                }
            }
        }

      }
      done();         
  })
```

Comment: What if you remove the `done` callback?

Comment: tried removing done, it doesn't solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. async run those functions which may take long time.
2. add exit flag, mocha will terminate process when test finished even async function still running. ex: mocha \"test/**/*.js\" --exit